# Getting a table in XML with same node name and property value how to write code for this

Tags: xml, xslt

Need Help to write XSL code for XML which having same property/attribute with same node name.

I tried the `<xsl:for-each`. It helps, but it is printing the first value only for every table rows.

XML Which I am Getting

```
<PLMXML>
  <Form>
    <TableRow id="id15" subType="new_part_no_row" tablePropertyName="new_part_no" index="0">    
      <ApplicationRef version="j8Tt$2HDltBKvA" label="j8Tt$2HDltBKvA" application="Teamcenter"/>  
      <TableColumn title="item_no" value="vbzvb"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow id="id16" subType="new_part_no_row" tablePropertyName="new_part_no" index="1">
      <ApplicationRef version="j8Yt$2HDltBKvA" label="j8Yt$2HDltBKvA" application="Teamcenter"/>  
      <TableColumn title="item_no" value="vvb"/>  
    </TableRow>
  </Form>
</PLMXML>
```

The XSL code:

```
<table border="0" bordercolor="black" align="left" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
    <tr></tr>
</table>
<br/>

<table border="0" bordercolor="black" align="left" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>
                <font size="4">
                    <font color="#000080">TABLE PROP</font>
                </font>
            </strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="0" bordercolor="black" align="left" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
    <tr></tr>
</table>

<table border="1" bordercolor="black" align="left" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" width="50%" height="5%">

    <th>Item NO</th>
    <th>Desc</th>
    <xsl:for-each select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:Form/plm:TableRow">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:Form/plm:TableRow[@title='item_no' and @index=current()/@index]/@value"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

I would like to display the output like below.

```
ITEM NO
vbzvb 
vvb
```

Comment: <TableRow id="id15" subType="CP9_new_part_no_row" tablePropertyName="cp9_new_part_no" index="0">

<ApplicationRef version="j8Tt$2HDltBKvA" label="j8Tt$2HDltBKvA" application="Teamcenter"/>

<TableColumn title="cp9_item_no" value="vbzvb"/>

</TableRow>


<TableRow id="id16" subType="CP9_new_part_no_row" tablePropertyName="cp9_new_part_no" index="1">

<ApplicationRef version="j8Yt$2HDltBKvA" label="j8Yt$2HDltBKvA" application="Teamcenter"/>

<TableColumn title="cp9_item_no" value=" vvb"/>

</TableRow>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and format your code properly (as I did for you just now). And show minimal, but **complete** examples of the input, the current XSLT and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `xsl:for-each` you are positioned on a `TableRow` element, meaning the xpath expression in your `xsl:value-of` can be relative to that. But by using `/` at the start of the expression you are ignoring the current node and instead beginning the search from the document node.

You can just do this to get the `TableColumn` for the "item_no"

```
<xsl:value-of select="plm:TableColumn[@title='item_no']/@value"/>
```

Try this XSLT (which you can see in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNx). Note you will have to change the namespace declaration for `plm` to match whatever it actually is in your real XML

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:plm="plm.test">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1" bordercolor="black" align="left" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" width="50%" height="5%">
      <tr>
        <th>Item NO</th>
        <th>Desc</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:Form/plm:TableRow">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="plm:TableColumn[@title='item_no']/@value"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="plm:TableColumn[@title='desc']/@value"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```